# Jekyll website hanging on some machines

Tags: performance

I'm drawing a blank and hope that someone has a pointer as to what could be causing my site to suddenly come to a standstill.

Disclaimer: I coded this site using https://github.com/ColeTownsend/Balzac-for-Jekyll/blob/master/_includes/head-dark.html around 3-4 years ago. Since then I have switched careers, and I rarely hit an editor nowadays.

An example page I'm experiencing problems with can be found here: http://deanbirkett.name/articles/looking-back-at-csun

What's happening is that when I open the page up myself on my own machine, the page half loads and then stops... the spinning wheel continues, but nothing else happens. Eventually the page times out and I have to kill the tab.

This happens to me in Safari and Chrome. Others have reported the same issue... yet others have reported absolutely no problems at all with the site/page(s).

This doesn't appear to be related to location - on one machine in my apartment I see no problems, on another it does what is described above.

I'm drawing a blank as to what can be going wrong - any ideas?

Comment: You're using a lot of external ressources that can be blocking.

Comment: Thanks @DavidJacquel I commented out the Hotjar code and all works fine.